# REGEX PHP ANY DIGITS QUANTITY 0-9

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I need to validate a regex where between STRING_{here}G_ can be 0 or even 4 digits, I tried the following regex:

```
(?<=TEST_[0-9]{0,4}G_).*
```

But the tester returns the error:

Your pattern contains one or more errors, please see the explanation section above.

And when trying to use manually, using two [0-9], it doesn't get my strings

```
ABC_TEST_20G_a123-abc1
ABC_TEST_100G_abc1
```

I need a regex that validates both strings and returns what is after G_
Remembering that the regex must have the "TEST_", it is a string that I need to validate

Comment: `?<=` is for Lookbehind conditionals. Do you really need that?

Comment: Most regular expression engines require lookbehinds to be fixed-size. So you can't have `{0,4}` in a lookbehind.

Comment: You could use a capture group instead `TEST_[0-9]{0,4}G_(.*)` https://regex101.com/r/eDM5GO/1 Note that `.*` matches zero or more times, so you might also match an empty string.

Comment: Instead of using lookbehind, you could use `\K` in this regex: `TEST_\d{0,4}G_\K.*`

Comment: Why is this tagged `[mysql]`?  Show us how you hope to use it in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most regexp engines don't allow lookbehinds to be variable-length, so you can't have a `{0,4}` quantifier in it.

Instead of a lookbehind, use a capture group to capture everything after this pattern.

```
TEST_[0-9]{0,4}G_(.*)
```

Capture group 1 will contain what you want to get.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qFBDc1/1)